# Compiler version for Linux Kernel compilation

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, cross-compiling

How to know which compiler version we need to use to compile a specific Linux Kernel Version? Can we get the compiler version information from the Linux Kernel Source? Say if I want to compile Linus Kernel Source 4.18 then which cross compiler version I need to select.

Comment: Yes.  You can get it from the source.  Start at the file named README in the top source directory.

Answer (score 1):

The Kernel is pretty *insensitive* to the compiler version.

According to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/process/changes.html, the minimum GCC version for compiling the Linux kernel is (currently<sup>1</sup>) GCC 5.1.

Notes:

1. This is a minimum version.  Assuming that you are building on an existing Linux box, the GCC version in the compiler toolchain is likely to be more recent than this.  Under normal circumstances, that should be fine.
2. If you are cross-compiling for an esoteric hardware platform, you may want to check for the existence of known GCC bugs / fixes for your target platform and choose your GCC version accordingly.

---

<sup>1 - Currently, as of the time of writing of this answer.  Check what the link says.</sup>